# "Он пришел вместе с ней"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте. Это предложение правильное:"Он пришел вместе с ней"?

Comment: student, не сочтите за оскорбление, у Вас русский - родной?
Если нет, то отвечающим стоит это знать. Методика объяснения совершенно другая. 
Ну а если я ошибаюсь - еще раз простите - то некоторые Ваши вопросы и толкования просто ставят в тупик.

Comment: Ну,не знаю,с рождения 20 лет говорил только на русском и других языков не знал ,Сейчас знаю несколько языков, а грамматику арабского лучше русского.Судите Сами родной он мне или нет.А Вы откройте любой учебник арабского языка, там грамматика по-другому построена,я же здесь задаю вопросы ,для того, чтобы сравнить и узнать что сходится ,а что нет,для того, чтобы объясняя грамматику арабского, быть уверенным.И еще, не обижайтесь, что Вы меня не понимаете,такое бывает.И Вам не кажется ,что многие из тех,которые сидят в чатах, намного хуже меня пишут ,интересно, русский язык родной для них или нет

Comment: Очень интересно, если на арабском  скажут написать сначала стол, а потом стул, Вы как поступите?

Comment: художник видит то , чего не видим мы,самый легкий вопрос может оказаться самым трудным,иногда я,просто,хочу,чтобы на мои ответили вы,филологи ,и не все мои вопросы связаны с арабским,я очень уважаю филологов ,прошу на меня не обижаться,спасибо всем!!!

Comment: в моем вопросе не было слова "сначала"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему нет? Само по себе правильное. А в контексте могут возникнуть стилистические недочеты в употреблении личных местоимений.

Comment: А разве "вместе" и "с" не одно и тоже? И исправьте ошибки,пожалуйста,если что то неправильно написал.

Comment: Ошибка у Вас: то же -раздельно, частица ЖЕ пишется отдельно, её можно опустить: одно и то...

Comment: Что-то - неопределённое местоимение, пишется через дефис с кое-, -то, -либо, -нибудь. (Ошибка в комментарии).

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!

Comment: Вместе с - производный предлог. образован от наречия вместе и непроизводного предлога С. Указывает на совместность.

Answer (score 1):

Всё верно. Наречие "вместе" часто употребляется с предлогом С, появляется смысл СОВМЕСТНО С...

Comment: Спасибо!!! А это предложение правильное:"Имя с предлогом вместе является сказуемым или нужно написать:"Являются сказуемым"?

Comment: "Являются ..."

Comment: спасибо!!!

Comment: Но мне кажется, здесь лучше сказать "Имя вместе с предлогом  является ..." - тогда -ет.

Comment: а если я сказал(не написал):"имя с предлогом вместе является..." это грубая ошибка,все переделывать?

Comment: Ну, не грубая, кто как поймёт. Если это не филологи, то пойдёт, там нюансы согласования. Если не филфак, переделывать не надо,коли  с этим сложности.

Comment: большое спасибо!!! а если без слова вместе говорить,например сказать:"Имя с предлогом является...",так не лучше будет?